# Highlight different keywords with different colours in vim

Tags: vim, neovim, log-analysis

Using Vim for Log analysis with the inbuilt VIM search functionality and hlsearch, I'd like to assign a different colour for each search result I get.

For e.g entries of my log would be.

1. CHECKPOINT 1
2. CHECKPOINT 2
3. CHECKPOINT 3
4. CHECKPOINT 4
5. CHECKPOINT ..
6. CHECKPOINT ..
7. .....
8. CHECKPOINT N

My requirement is to search all these checpoints, and have Checkpoint in a different colour. But visible at same time in the screen.

1. CHECKPOINT 1 - Highlighted as orange
2. CHECKPOINT 2 - Highlighted as Green
3. CHECKPOINT 3 - Highlighted as Red and so on
4. CHECKPOINT 4
5. CHECKPOINT ..
6. CHECKPOINT ..
7. .....
8. CHECKPOINT N

Do you know if it's possible to achieve this on vim?? or could you suggest some other tools that would be useful for this.

Thank you :)

used /CHECKPOINT to search for all checkpoints and hlsearch to highlight each match.

Comment: Reading [`:help mysyntaxfile`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile) should get you started.

Comment: See `:help :match`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Friedrich this gets the exact same results I desired.

Comment: Thank you so much @romainl this gets the exact same results I desired.